# How can I fix Could not create Relay Container for `Link`

Tags: javascript, graphql-js, relayjs, relay

I try to follow [the tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/react-relay/2-queries-loading-links/) about GraphQL and Relay.

And when I run it (or run `yarn test`):

```
Invariant Violation: Could not create Relay Container for `Link`. Expected a set of GraphQL fragments, got `function () {
      const node = require("./__generated__/Link_link.graphql");

      if (node.hash && node.hash !== "4db5e0eb9875bd761c8f8ef68ea507f3") {
        console.error("The definition of 'Link_link' appears to have changed. Run `relay-compiler` to update the generated files to receive the expected data.");
      }

      return require("./__generated__/Link_link.graphql");
    }` instead.

      16 | }
      17 |
    > 18 | export default createFragmentContainer(Link, graphql`
         |                ^
      19 |     fragment Link_link on Link {
      20 |         id
      21 |         description

      at invariant (node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:40:15)
```

I tried to modify `graphql.schema`:

```
type Link implements Node {
  id: ID!
  description: String!
  url: String!
}
```

to match

```
export default createFragmentContainer(Link, graphql`
    fragment Link_link on Link {
        id
        description
        url
    }
`)
```

yet I receive the same error. Also I tried to remove `__generated__` folder and rerun `relay-compiler` with no success.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem when upgrading to `v4.0.0`. It seems that they've removed support for passing the `graphql` literal as the second argument, so instead you should pass an object like

```
export default createFragmentContainer(Link, {
  link: graphql`
    fragment Link_link on Link {
      id
      description
      url
    }
  `
})
```

It's annoying but it should work. I hope they fix this issue for future versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is an addition to [hisa_py's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/667598/hisa-py) answer:

```
export default createFragmentContainer(ModuleName, {
  moduleName: graphql`                             // LINE 2
    fragment Link_link on Link {
      id
      description
      url
    }
  `
})
```

Notice how **only** the first character is to be lowercased at line 2.